# Flutter: image-rendering do CSS equivalente no Flutter

Tags: css3, imagem, flutter, dart, processamento-de-imagens

Tenho uma API que retorna pixel art's, essa API retorna apenas imagens com tamanho pequeno: 25x25, 50x50.

- ### Problema

Como as imagens são bem pequenas não é possível mostrar essas imagens em uma resolução maior, (por exemplo: 900x900, 350x350, 600x600)

- ### Solução na Web

Para exibir estas imagens pixeladas na web utilizo a propriedade `image-rendering` do CSS com valor `pixelated`, isso faz com que a imagem pixelada fique em alta resolução independente do tamanho

```html
<img src="..." width="1200" height="1200" style="image-rendering: pixelated"> <!-- Ok -->
```

- #### Solução no Flutter

Qual a abordagem necessária para utilizar algo parecido com `image-rendering: pixelated` no Flutter?
Algo como:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Image.network('...', rendering: ImageRendering.pixelated);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) dessa propriedade, temos que o valor `pixelated` significa:

> When scaling the image up, the nearest-neighbor algorithm must be used, so that the image appears to be composed of large pixels. When scaling down, this is the same as auto.

Isto é, do inglês: Quando aumentado o tamanho da imagem, o [algoritmo de vizinho mais próximo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_vizinho_mais_pr%C3%B3ximo) deve ser utilizado. (Tradução livre).

Ao olhar a [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) dos construtores do widget `Image`, vemos a seguinte propriedade `FilterQuality`:

> Use filterQuality to change the quality when scaling an image. Use the FilterQuality.low quality setting to scale the image, which corresponds to bilinear interpolation, rather than the default FilterQuality.none which corresponds to nearest-neighbor.

Isto é, essa propriedade representa a mudança de qualidade quando se muda o tamanho de uma imagem. Para usar o algoritmo de vizinho mais próximo, usa-se o valor `FilterQuality.none`. Este é o resultado desejado na pergunta.

Segundo seu exemplo, fica:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Image.network('...', filterQuality: FilterQuality.none);
}
```

Vale deixar claro que essa propriedade está presente nos outros construtores do widget `Image` (por exemplo `Image.Asset()`, etc..)

Para ver outros valores que a propriedade `filterQuality` pode obter, leia [aqui](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FilterQuality-class.html).